# Solution to the flexible heights

Tags: html, css, height

I got 4 columns and I decided to set a height value to them as I like them to appear ending at the same line but I'm working on a flexible layout, I mean, when the browser is resized down and the page gets narrower, the heights of the boxes should extend. So how do I set the heights of boxes evenly without setting a height value?

Comment: did you tried min-height ? rather than height

Comment: `height:auto` should work. or not mentioning anything also should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all the columns to be the same height, if I understand correctly.

You can fix that by displaying the divs as table-cells, like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body > div {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Also check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/Hverq/). Click in column one to add some extra text (just so you can see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you will need javascript to do it.

[Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/old-flexbox-and-new-flexbox/) does what you want, but it's right between two specifications and very poorly supported at the moment as browsers are very far apart in which specification they support, so regrettably it's not really an option at this stage..

You can create your own with javascript. or use a [flexbox polyfill](https://github.com/doctyper/flexie)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this. Try below link.

http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

[Demo](http://css-tricks.com/examples/FluidEqualHeightFauxColumns/)